# Hash on an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array in Ruby which looks like this:

```
@arr = [ [2.1, pass], 
         [2.1, fail],
         [2.1, pass],
         [2.1, unknown],
         [2.1, pass],
         [3.0, pass],
         [3.0, unknown],
         [3.1, pass],
         [3.1, fail] ]
```

I want to apply some kind of hashing or computation on it such that my output should be an array like:

```
@result = [ [2.1, 3, 1, 1],
            [3.0, 1, 0, 1],
            [3.1, 1, 1, 0] ]
```

The output array displays results in this format {version, no.of pass, no.of fail, no.of unknown}

Comment: What you've posted is not valid Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I translate your expression a bit...

```
@arr = [
  [2.1, :pass],
  [2.1, :fail],
  [2.1, :pass],
  [2.1, :unknown],
  [2.1, :pass],
  [3.0, :pass],
  [3.0, :unknown],
  [3.1, :pass],
  [3.1, :fail]]
```

Then the problem can be solved with...

```
@arr.group_by(&:first).values.map do |x|
  y = x.flatten
  [y[0], y.count(:pass), y.count(:fail), y.count(:unknown)]
end
```

Comment: Oh, and if you wanted to DIE/DRY the three `count` method calls, I suppose you could do this: `[:pass, :fail, :unknown].map { |e| y.count e }`

Comment: 'pass', 'fail' and 'unknown' are all strings in my array. I tried the above code. I had a question. Is y the output array ? If yes, how do i access that in my html.erb file.....I usually put a @ before the variable name to access it from my view(html.erb) file.

Comment: `y` is just a temporary inside the block passed to `#map`. I didn't show an output variable. It would look like `@result = @arr.group_by(&:first) ...` or maybe just `result = ...`. You can paste my example into irb and experiment with it, perhaps use Strings instead of Symbols, etc.

Comment: It does not show the count of pass, fail and unknown... shows all zeros...all these are strings i guess. And also the pass would be 'Pass' or 'pass'. How do I resolve this ?

Comment: You should probably change my demo to use `'pass'` instead of `:pass`, etc. Experiment in irb. The example as written does work.

Comment: one last question, If i want to add one more column to count the total, what would that look like? I tried y.count(all) and a few other combinations.

Comment: Change the last expression to `[y[0], y.count(:pass), y.count(:fail), y.count(:unknown), y.count/2]`

Answer (score 0):

Those are not valid hashes. Hashes must have keys associated with them. This is a hash of the arrays in your initial example:

```
@arr = { something: [2.1, pass], 
         somethingelse: [2.1, fail],
         another: [2.1, pass],
         andanother: [2.1, unknown],
         whatever: [2.1, pass],
         whateverelse: [3.0, pass],
         key: [3.0, unknown],
         anotherkey: [3.1, pass],
         yetanother: [3.1, fail] }
```

Hashes are marked with { and }. Arrays are [ and ]. If you want to have an array of arrays, you do with that [ and ].